# Linking TFS-workitem to external git

Tags: git, tfs, workitem

we're using a git server. Now we also want to use the Team Foundation Server, for tracking our issues, bugs and tasks. Is there any possibility, to use TFS with a external git server.

I know, there is a git-server included in TFS, but we want to keep our current server.

Especially we are interested in linking our workitems to the changes in git.

Thanks

Comment: you want to use TFS on-Prem or VSTS ?

Answer (score 0):

TFS supports the external Git. You can link the work items to external git with REST API, see [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

You can also have a try with this extension : [External Git WorkItem Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlmaToolBoxCE.ExternalGitWIIntegration). This task allows you to associate external git changes with Work Item defined in a comment of a last commit

Comment: I think the answer is valid for VSTS and not TFS on-prem.Are you sure that question is related to VSTS ?

Comment: @Elias22 Have you resolved the issue? any update? If the answer helps you could vote it up, it that resolved your issue, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread